# how to convert pdf to flipbook in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf-generation

how to convert pdf to flipbook in html.
if example is upload pdf file to stored in database and display  html page

view retrived from database viewed by flipbook-html .is it possible?

plesase tell me procedure.
pdf uploaded to automatic  convert flipbook to view in html or php.

refer examples sites:
http://www.pdf-flip.com/demos/PDF_Flip_Page_Converter_Demo_006.html#PDF/1